English equivalent for the idiom "mother-in-law has forgotten to wear her saree (dress)"
What is the equivalent idiom in English to my mother tongue saying "It is like my mother-in-law has forgotten to wear her saree when she is happy about her new son's-in-law arrival at her house"?
It is used to express that somebody is in an unnecessary hurry when they need to do something soberly. The witty expression makes the expression very poignant and very effective. For example, if I forgot to bring my hall ticket in an unnecessary hurry, somebody may use the idiom against me laughingly because I have forgotten the most important thing for the exam.

@Jvlnarasimharao How is the situation humorous? There's a lot of cultural context that's probably relevant to making the quip funny. Is the MiL thought to be naked without her sari? Please add all these details in comments to your original question.

Also, what is a 'hall ticket' and what does that have to do with an exam? is the ticket to prove that you are the student taking the exam (to prevent cheating)? (ie hall ticket may be a specific Indian English term, I just don't know what the concept it relates to is). Fun question, whatever the details.

@Mitch I think the OP is looking for an idiom which captures a situation like this: Imagine a person who's taken care of every possible detail but the main thing (without which the other details taken care of are naturally rendered meaningless.) So the person in question becomes sorta a laughing stock for others because of this oversight. I'm sure you could come up with something worthwhile for such a scenario now.

Edits on this site are supposed to clarify posts, making their intended meaning easier to understand, and to incorporate additional information shared e.g. in comments (which are ephemeral). Rather than starting a heated debate about whose grammar and punctuation are better, I'd like to ask @Jvlnarasimharao a few questions: (1) Have the edits to your question made it easier to read and understand? (2) Does the edited question still match what you intended to ask? If the answer is yes to both, everything should be in order. If not, please edit your question yourself to fix it.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

The question is not at all opinion based but  culture specific and funny. In my 2 states it is frequently used and everybody knows why the idiom is used. It is not good to say something opinion based if we don't know it or understand it. Even God may be an opinion or belief but may not be truth or a fact. Everything is opinion based right from language to literature  .Nothing is absolute.Everything is relative

Yeah, "opinion based" was the wrong thing to close this under. "Lacks detail" or "lacks focus", yes, but not "opinion based"

I did see this duplicate question but none of the answers are very satisfactory. It may not be completely identical, but any answer to either is probably as close as you'll get to the other.


She would lose her head if it wasn't attached.


would lose one's head if it wasn't attached
(humorous) Said of a person who habitually mislays things.
Alternative forms
would lose one's head...
• if it wasn't bolted on
• if it wasn't glued on
• if it wasn't screwed on
• if it wasn't stuck on
• if it wasn't tied on
Wiktionary



Wide use of this technology will be positioned to promote greater
levels of personal safety from emerging world threats, as well as
offering a simple, convenient method for accessing the global
electronic marketplace as your monies can be downloaded into the chip
that resides in your hand or forehead instead of your plastic Smart
Card. The direct benefit is that no one can physically steal your
card, nor can it become lost or misplaced. This gives new meaning to
the phrase "I would lose my head if it wasn't attached."
Lee Kedrie; A Thief in the Night (2006)


"That man would have lost his head if it wasn't attached to his
shoulders. Do people still say that, Dave? I mean about people
losing their heads." I tell her I used to know a man who said it all
the time.
Ben Graham; Ending in Angles (2007)

Tracy Chesney; "I’d probably lose my head if it wasn’t attached to my
body" at RoyseCityHeraldBanner.com (2008)

Slightly more humorous version He/She would lose their head if it wasn't screwed on. Possible hints of Frankenstein's monster if applicable.

@PeterJennings I've added the alternative forms from the Wiktionary entry, which includes that one :)

I use (in the UK) "I'd forget my brain if it wasn't screwed in!" to make light of my absentmindedness

OP's situation seems unusual rather than habitual.


It is used to express that somebody is in an unnecessary hurry when they need to do something soberly

In Australia, "You'd forget your arse if it wasn't attached."
OP, it's somewhat unclear what the sense of the phrase is to be honest.
You may well be thinking of More hurry, less speed. or Haste makes waste as mentioned, or conceivably A stitch in time saves nine.

I would say 'More haste, less speed', personally. I'm not sure I've every heard the phrase with 'hurry'.

@aantia yeah it's interesting I've noticed those variations are regional.   I've only ever heard "haste" used in the .makes waste one.  And - I think but am not certain - "More hurry, less speed" is less/not used in the USA

Sounds similar to:
"She's running around like a chicken with it's head cut off."
It just means she's so busy she can hardly stay on top of everything. It is said with minimal humor (or perhaps minimal negativity). It would not generally be thought of as offensive. It's an old saying and sounds like something Grandma would have said because she did.
Answer from:
American, male, 40s, lower-middle income.

One idiom that could be used jocularly is

She's away with the fairies.

Urban Dictionary allows for the temporary abstracted state:


Away with the fairies

The expression means to be in a daydream, to be in one's own world,
sometimes to be deep in thought and having one's gaze unfocused.

But care has to be exercised; it is often rather cruelly used for a more serious, lasting, condition:


away with the fairies [idiomatic]:

[1] Not all there; slightly crazy.
...

[Wiktionary]


away with the fairies
[informal]:

out of touch with reality

[Collins]


away with the fairies:

Apparently of Irish-English origin, the phrase away with the fairies means giving the impression of being mad,
distracted, or in a dreamworld.

[Pascal Tréguer; Word Histories]


away with the fairies:

When you hear the expression away with the fairies, you imagine someone rather useless. Someone chronically
distracted, with a short attention span and no common sense. Someone –
if we’re not being polite – a bit batty.

[Zoë Marriott; RLF]
......................
Probably safer is 'She's in a dream' (not 'in a dream world'):

be in a dream [UK]:
B2. to not notice things that are around you because you are thinking
about something else.

[Cambridge Dictionary]
I'd say there is more a hint of euphoria than of apprehension, or even of just everyday distraction.

Not quite. I don't think this captures the nuance of the situation in question. It's simply an idiomatic way of saying that the person in question is absentminded. Not my dv, by the way.
